# ionic toggles not affecting the right local storage item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, local-storage

Having an issue with ionic toggles, where which ever toggle you change it only effects the last if statement below in local storage.

This is the list of toggles...

```
$scope.settingsList = [

    { text: "GBP", checked: gbpON },
    { text: "USD", checked: usdON },
    { text: "EURO", checked: euroON },
    { text: "AUD", checked: audON },
    { text: "CAD", checked: cadON },
    { text: "YEN", checked: yenON }
];
```

This is the HTML...

```
<div class="list">  
    <ion-toggle ng-repeat="item in settingsList"
                ng-model="item.checked" 
                ng-checked="item.checked"
                ng-change="toggleONOFF({{item.text}})"
                toggle-class="toggle-royal">
      {{item.text}}
    </ion-toggle>
</div>
```

and this is what happens when you click the toggle...

```
$scope.toggleONOFF = function($var) {

    // GBP is toggled
    if ($var = "GBP") {   

        if (localStorage.getItem("gbpON") == "true") {  

            localStorage.setItem("gbpON", false);

        } else {

            localStorage.setItem("gbpON", true);    
        }
    };

    // USD is toggled
    if ($var = "USD") {   

        if (localStorage.getItem("usdON") == "true") {  

            localStorage.setItem("usdON", false);

        } else {

            localStorage.setItem("usdON", true);    
        }
    };

    // EURO is toggled
    if ($var = "EURO") {   

        if (localStorage.getItem("euroON") == "true") {  

            localStorage.setItem("euroON", false);

        } else {

            localStorage.setItem("euroON", true);    
        }
    }

    // AUD is toggled
    if ($var = "AUD") {   

        if (localStorage.getItem("audON") == "true") {  

            localStorage.setItem("audON", false);

        } else {

            localStorage.setItem("audON", true);    
        }
    }

    // CAD is toggled
    if ($var = "CAD") {   

        if (localStorage.getItem("cadON") == "true") {  

            localStorage.setItem("cadON", false);

        } else {

            localStorage.setItem("cadON", true);    
        }
    }

    // YEN is toggled
    if ($var = "YEN") {   

        if (localStorage.getItem("yenON") == "true") {  

            localStorage.setItem("yenON", false);

        } else {

            localStorage.setItem("yenON", true);    
        }
    }
}
```

The problem i have is which ever toggle you press it only changes the yen in local storage and not the one its linked to. For example toggleONOFF(GBP)

Answer (score 0):

I believe adding `;` in the `if-else` statement is the culprit also you need to initialize your localStorage with some value or check condition before using it raw in an if-else statement.

```
if ($var = "GBP") {   
    if (localStorage.getItem("gbpON") == "true") {  
        localStorage.setItem("gbpON", false);
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("gbpON", true);    
    }
};
```